# Can't save photo. Camera doesn't have permission to save to this location [Only happening to Google Pixel phones]

Tags: java, android, android-studio, scoped-storage, google-pixel

I am currently facing an issue with Google pixel phones not letting the app save photo to a specific file location (mentioned below). I don't know if this is something to do with the scoped-storage because the **app is running perfectly fine with 4000+ android 12 devices and this only happens to google pixel devices.**

> (content://com.au.APP_NAME/data/user/0/com.au.APP_NAME/cache/APP_NAMEPicture-Cache/1660.jpg)

```
private void startCameraIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        String filePath = FileProvider.contentUri + StorageManager.createPictureCacheFileName(getContext());

//filePath = content://com.au.APP_NAME/data/user/0/com.au.APP_NAME/cache/APP_NAMEPicture-Cache/1660.jpg
 
        StorageManager.saveCameraCaptureImageFilePathToSharedPreferences(getContext(), filePath);

        Uri fileURI = Uri.parse(filePath);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileURI);

      
        startActivityForResult(intent, Constant.TAKE_PHOTO_FROM_CAMERA_ACTIVITY_TAG);
        
      
    }
```

Comment: Are you creating the cache directory before using an intent?

Comment: yes, I am creating the cache dir before using intent.

Comment: You should use FileProvider.getUriFromFile() to get a usable content scheme uri. That one you builded cannot work. Try to open an outputstream for it and write to it yourself to find out.

Comment: Also the intent is missing a WRITE permission flag.